# Using UIStatusBarLightContent for iOS6 compatible app crashing

Tags: objective-c, ios6, ios7

I have an app the I built in iOS7 but am trying to compile it for iOS6. My settings are Base SDK 7.0 and Deployment Target 6.0, however this line of code is causing the app to fail build:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

It says that its a use of undeclared identifier. How do I get around this?

Comment: Which is it? A crash or a build error? Big difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of lightContent is

```
UIStatusBarStyleLightContent     NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0) = 1
```

to get it to build in ios6 you can replace the value with 1.  It isn't very clean but it is simple.

```
#ifndef UIStatusBarStyleLightContent
#define UIStatusBarStyleLightContent 1
#endif
```

would also work but is just as hackey.

Comment: The code doesn't seem to be working for me. Where do I add it? I was trying to add it to my AppDelegate.m If you could give me the full code that would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can put the ifndef part at the top of the file where you do setStatusBarStyle

Comment: rmaddy, it is something that happens when you do a build using the 6.0 sdks or something similar where the `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` value is not defined.

Comment: But the OP stated that the Base SDK is iOS 7, not iOS 6.